# Facebook notifications RSS feed

Tags: facebook, rss, notifications

Good day

When I want to view my RSS feed of my notifications Facebook gives me this URL
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=100001444273394&viewer=100001444273394&key=AWiVVNlBfK8I9PcN&format=rss20

How is the key generated? (I've changed the value for safety sake)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you change your Facebook account password, the "Key" parameter will change too.